# Deepin Update: end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknow-block(0,0)

Tags: debian, deepin

After the new update of deepin 15.6 this error is showing while booting up.

Comment: Debian Tag: "Questions specific to the Debian official distribution (stable, testing, or unstable); if you are using a derivative of Debian (e.g. Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, etc), then use that distribution’s tag instead." Deepin NOT Debian...

Comment: @arochester Deepin is based on Debian, that's why I used that tag mate.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is not able to access the device that contains the root filesystem.

Possible causes:

- a typo in kernel boot parameters (unlikely in your case)
- an error in building initramfs/initrd: either the initramfs has not been built at all, or a driver that is necessary for accessing the root filesystem has been omitted.

If the bootloader menu includes an option to boot with the previous kernel version, try that: the initramfs/initrd file for that kernel version should remain unchanged after the update.

If you can successfully boot with the previous kernel, then check the sizes of the initramfs/initrd files, usually located in `/boot`: they are usually named something like `initrd.img-<kernel version>` or `initramfs-<kernel version>`. If the initramfs file for the new kernel is significantly smaller than the respective file for the older kernel, it is very likely that the new file is incomplete and needs to be recreated.

In Debian and related distributions, you can usually use `update-initramfs` to recreate the initramfs file. The command should be `update-initramfs -u -k <new kernel version>`.

Comment: What if grub doesn't work "Loading Grub" and then it immediately jumps to the error in the subject. LiveCD with 16.04 -> I can get into "Try Ubuntu" but there's no recovery mode within LiveCD.. is there a way to run this on /dev/sdX in terms of initramfs for the kernel?

Comment: @mederomuraliev "Kernel panic - not syncing" is unquestionably from the Linux kernel, so GRUB actually managed to load and start the kernel (and the initramfs file, assuming there is one configured). But the kernel failed to find the root filesystem, possibly because it could not find a driver that would have allowed the kernel to access it (usually either a disk controller driver, or a filesystem driver). That means either an incomplete initramfs file, or a kernel configuration error if you are using custom kernels.

Comment: @mederomuraliev With a LiveCD, you can mount your installed system and chroot into it to e.g. run `update-initramfs -u -k <kernel-version>` to rebuild the initramfs file of a particular kernel version. Make sure your filesystem has enough free space before you try that. And if you have more to ask, please make your own question post instead of adding comments to this one.